# Unity3D C# positioning of panel after instantiation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, panel, rect

I'm instantiating a GO that has a panel component (**RectTransform**) as child of a canvas existing in the scene:

```
_heroSelectUI = (GameObject)Instantiate (_heroSelectUIPrefab, GameObject.Find ("Canvas").GetComponent<Transform>());
```

When it's created it gets the following values:

[image: Panel Values]

"Left", "Top", "Right" and "Bottom" get some **unwanted values** (probably due to the existing canvas which seems to have identical values).

The panels **prefabs values are 0**, how to **set them back to 0** after instantiation? I can't find the proper variables for the RectTransform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html)

> For a stretching Rect Transform, it can be simpler to set the position using the offsetMin and offsetMax properties. The [offsetMin](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-offsetMin.html) property specifies the corner of the lower left corner of the rect relative to the lower left anchor. The [offsetMax](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform-offsetMax.html) property specifies the corner of the upper right corner of the rect relative to the upper right anchor.

Try to do as follow :

```
RectTransform rt = _heroSelectUI.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.offsetMin = rt.offsetMax = Vector2.zero ;
```

---

Else, according to the documentation too, you can try to do it when setting the parent :

> Prefabs of UI elements are instantiated as normal using the Instantiate method. When setting the parent of the instantiated UI element, it’s recommended to do it using the Transform.SetParent method with the worldPositionStays parameter set to false.

```
_heroSelectUI = (GameObject)Instantiate (_heroSelectUIPrefab, GameObject.Find ("Canvas").GetComponent<RectTransform>(), false);
```

OR :

```
_heroSelectUI = (GameObject)Instantiate (_heroSelectUIPrefab );
_heroSelectUI.GetComponent<Transform>().SetParent( GameObject.Find ("Canvas").GetComponent<RectTransform>(), false ) ;
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I've been setting in to false for my buttons but didn't think about doing this with the panel also! It has done the job as well setting worldPositionStays to false.